# Android app fails to install on 4.2.2. but works on newer versions.

Tags: android, certificate, titanium-mobile

I have created an app in Titanium Studio but it does not install on one of my devices which is running 4.2.2. The min SDK setting in the manifest is correct but I get the following error when trying to install the app:

`E/PackageParser(456): Package my.app.package has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml; ignoring!`

My Setup:

- OSX: 10.11.3
- Android 4.2.2
- Java 1.8.0_45
- Titanium SDK: 5.2.0.GA

I checked the certificate and it seems ok. Any suggestions on what the issue could be?

Comment: add some more logs. It seems that older Android do not read your certificate correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDK 8 keytool uses SHA256 as default whereas Android 4.3 and below only support APKs being signed with SHA1.
Use the following command to generate a certificate with the appropriate algorithm:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA1withRSA ...
```

You may check your old and new certificate with

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <CERTIFICATE-STORE>
```